# Garbage Collector too slow in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, garbage-collection

I have a foreach loop where I do some operations with images. I was getting an `OutOfMemoryException` when running this code with 50+ images; because the image instances are 15+ MB each.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Image image = new Bitmap(file);

    //Do some operations
}
```

I removed the main logic because this problem still exists with this small piece of code. When I add `GC.Collect();` in the foreach loop the problem is gone and I don't get an exception.

My question is: is the garbage collector too slow to clean up the images which aren't needed anymore without calling the `Collect` method or am I missing something else?

Never noticed this problem before. I never thought there would be a problem because the `//Do some operations` part needs ~1 second for each image. Should be enough time for the garbage collector I thought.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: as far as I can see it is a duplicate - OP is suffering Out Of Memory issues when using Bitmaps - that is because GC will not automatically handle the unmanaged memory. The solution given answers the question. See also answer by Romano below.

Comment: @PaulF Ok, I missed something else...Should have thought about the use of `Bitmap`. Thank you!

Comment: @YvetteColomb: OP says the automatic cleaning up is slow to happen and out of memory issues occur - UNLESS Collect is manually called. OP does not say the call to Collect is the issue & has accepted the answer given.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It really was a duplicate. Haven't thought about disposing the `Bitmap` and thought the GC was the problem.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: The original question the Mighty Bababoom came with was _"My question is: is the garbage collector too slow to clean up the images which aren't needed anymore without calling the Collect method or am I missing something else?"_ - in which case the answer was "Yes - you missed the fact that you need to Dispose bitmaps - otherwise GC will be very slow at collecting the images" - both parts of the answer addressed in the duplicate question. No change midstream.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I just did a quick search on something like "C# Bitmap GC slow memory leak" - lots of questions on here - I just thought  that one was a best fit as it discussed memory errors when creating bitmaps in a loop & the problem going away when GC manually called & gave a reason for the apparent slowness in collection. This was at the top of the list & could have been a better choice : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366247/garbage-collector-too-slow-when-working-with-large-images - but the answers are not as well explained.

Comment: this is a good read, go to no 8: https://www.toptal.com/c-sharp/top-10-mistakes-that-c-sharp-programmers-make

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should work with `using`:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    using (Image image = new Bitmap(file))
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

This way the `Bitmap` will be disposed after the iteration

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried explicitly disposing the instance?

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Image image = new Bitmap(file);

    //Do some operations
    image.Dispose();
    //image = null;
}
```

The same could be better implemented with `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with GC but with your use of bitmaps. Although GC will eventually pick them up, you need to wrap image creation in `using` block to ensure their timely disposal:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    using (Image image = new Bitmap(file)) {
        //Do some operations
    }
}
```